# Dynatree multi - selection implementaion ala Windows style

Tags: javascript, dynatree, jquery-dynatree

I would like to implement windows style multi-selection:

when user holds CTRL key and selects several nodes of the tree. 
Dynatree (from here http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/dynatree-doc.html) by default has checkboxes for node selection which my client doesn't seem to like.

My question is, is it possible to implement what I need using provided set of callbacks?
also, curently, when I hold CTRL key and click on the node, it opens a new window. 
Is there any way to suppress this functionality? i am guess I would have to do through CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the sample and source code here
  http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/sample-select.html

The last example on that page uses the `checkbox: false` tree option to hide the checkboxes.
The `onClick` handler calls `dtnode.toggleSelection()`.

This could be replaced by something like

```
if not CTRL pressed:
    deselect all nodes
toggle selection
```

Desecting all nodes could be done like this:

```
tree.visit(function(dtnode) {
    dtnode.select(false);
});
```

Comment: thank you! i will take a look. 
thanks for the great component, by the way. i love working with it.